# App subscription with Stripe SDK instead of Apple

Tags: ios, expo, stripe-payments

I want to implement a subscription into my app for more premium ussrs to active more analytics or features.

The app is build using Expo so using the Stripe React Native SDK would be the best solution.

But will this be allowex by apple to use Stripe instead of Apple In App Purchase API?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ "If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're selling something (like your App or a service), you need to use in-app purchases. However, if you're selling goods, you can use a service like Stripe.

Comment: We have a platform with a back-end API, a web app, and two mobile apps targeting Android/iOS. we're using Stripe for subscriptions and what we're selling is 3 different plans each with a different quota (e.g. how many records people can make per month, how much disk space they can use per month, etc.). Using Apple's IAP service is not an option, the mobile app is free to use, and there's nothing to be unlocked. Users need an account with an active subscription to have access to all 3 apps (web/android/ios). I'm confused as to what we can do to move forward.